# JVM ACCESS_VIOLATION_EXCEPTION when constructing String from array on obsolete JVM

Tags: java, string, java-6

I've run into a really weird case - I have the following code:

```
new String(data, position, len, Charset.forName("windows-1255"));
```

where `data` is a `byte[]`, and `position` and `len` are `int`s.
When I run it on jdk 1.6.0_38, it runs really slow (for a set iteration 411 seconds), and when I run this:

```
new String(data, position, len);
```

it runs the same iteration in less than 1 sec.
Some more data:

- When I debug it, upon entering the Constructor (with the Charset) it
  throws a JVM ACCESS_VIOLATION_EXCEPTION and dies.
- When I run it on jdk 1.7.0_10 it runs fine (less than 1 sec)

can anyone explain this weird behavior?

Comment: Can you post a minimal example that we can run ourselves to replicate the problem? How big is your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you ran into [this](http://java-performance.info/inefficient-byte-to-string-constructor/) issue. The article claims that the constructor you are using is inefficient, because it always makes a defensive copy of the provided byte[] buffer, which then can lead to frequent GCing. I guess if you do a long enough iteration, the performance differences can become that visible - just like it is mentioned in the article's summary.

As for the access vialoation, it seems to be [this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8021897?focusedCommentId=13392582&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13392582) problem.